# Ruby on Rails - Testing Mailer as a callback in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mailer

I have this logic where I send a welcome email to the user when it is created.

`User.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Callbacks
  after_create :send_registration_email

  private

  def send_registration_email
    UserConfirmationMailer.with(user: self).user_registration_email.deliver_later
  end 
end
```

I tried testing it in `user_spec.rb`:

```
describe "#save" do
 subject { create :valid_user }

 context "when user is created" do
   it "receives welcome email" do
     mail = double('Mail')
     expect(UserConfirmationMailer).to receive(:user_registration_email).with(user: subject).and_return(mail)
     expect(mail).to receive(:deliver_later)
   end
 end
end
```

But it is not working. I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(UserConfirmationMailer).to receive(:user_registration_email).with(user: subject).and_return(mail)
     
       (UserConfirmationMailer (class)).user_registration_email({:user=>#<User id: 5, email: "factory10@test.io", created_at: "2023-02-18 01:09:34.878424000 +0000", ...878424000 +0000", jti: "2163d284-1349-4e48-8a2a-1b52b578921c", username: "jose_test10", icon_id: 5>})
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:user=>#<User id: 5, email: "factory10@test.io", created_at: "2023-02-18 01:09:34.878424000 +0000", ...878424000 +0000", jti: "2163d284-1349-4e48-8a2a-1b52b578921c", username: "jose_test10", icon_id: 5>})
           received: 0 times
```

Am I doing something wrong when testing the action of sending the email in a callback?

PD.

My `environment/test.rb` config is as follows:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://localhost:3000" }
```

Even if I change `config.active_job.queue_adapter` to `:test` following [this](https://dev.to/jbranchaud/test-actionmailer-deliverlater-in-rspec-controller-tests-44h7), I get the same error.

Another way I am trying to do it is like this:

```
expect { FactoryBot.create(:valid_user) }.to  have_enqueued_job(ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob).with('UserConfirmationMailer', 'user_registration_email', 'deliver_now', subject)
```

But then `subject` and the user created in `FactoryBot.create(:valid_user)` is different..

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stubbing in the question doesn't work because it doesn't stub the chain of methods in the same order then they are called in the implementation.

When you want to stub this method chain

```
UserConfirmationMailer.with(user: self).user_registration_email.deliver_later
```

then you have to first stub the `with` call, then the `user_registration_email` and last the `deliver_later`.

```
describe '#save' do
  subject(:user) { build(:valid_user) }

  let(:parameterized_mailer) { instance_double('ActionMailer::Parameterized::Mailer') }
  let(:parameterized_message) { instance_double('ActionMailer::Parameterized::MessageDelivery') }

  before do 
    allow(UserConfirmationMailer).to receive(:with).and_return(parameterized_mailer)
    allow(parameterized_mailer).to receive(:user_registration_email).and_return(parameterized_message)
    allow(parameterized_message).to receive(:deliver_later)
  end

  context 'when user is created' do
    it 'sends a welcome email' do
      user.save!

      expect(UserConfirmationMailer).to have_received(:with).with(user: user)
      expect(parameterized_mailer).to have_received(:user_registration_email)
      expect(parameterized_message).to have_received(:deliver_later)
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I am not sure if using `instance_double` will work in this case, because the `Parameterized` uses `method_missing` internally. Although `instance_double` is usually preferred, you might need to use `double` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @spickermann . I tried it with `double` since `instance_double` is giving error. And it gives this error ` undefined method `to_have_received' ` for any of the 3 expectations

Comment: I fixed the typo `to_have_receive` to `to have_received` in my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you for the update @spickermann! It is still failing with this error 
`(UserConfirmationMailer (class)).with({:user=>#<User id: nil, email: "factory48@test.io", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, jti: nil, username: "jose_test48", icon_id: nil>})
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:user=>#<User id: nil, email: "factory48@test.io", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, jti: nil, username: "jose_test48", icon_id: nil>})
           received: 0 times`

Comment: The error message `expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:user=>#<User id: nil,...` indicates that the `user.save` call wasn't successful, otherwise the user should have had an `id` set. Did you double-check that there were not validation errors?

Comment: Got it now! User needed an associated model called Icon so I first needed to handle the creation of that instance so I could save user. Thanks so much!